# Regex for multiline search in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a regex in VScode for finding img lines without alt="" and title="" marks for SEO purposes and I can't find solutions for wrong formatted multi lines.

For example my regex:

```
<img((?!alt\=\".*\").)*((?!title\=\".*\").)*>
```

works for:

[image: example1]

but won't work for:

[image: example2].

I tried with something like:

```
<img\n*\t*\s*\r*((?!alt\=\".*\").)*((?!title\=\".*\").)*\n*\t*\s*\r*>
```

but it won't work also.

I'm looking for solution for this because I have 15k lines of html code with that second type of formatting (probably copy paste from wordpress post).

This is my example line if you would like to copy it:

```
<img class="img-responsive vertical-center" src="someImage.png" style="height: 65%; width: auto;" alt="" >
```

Comment: It should be something like `<img\b(?![^>]*\balt=")(?![^>]*\btitle=")[^>]*>` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2dWaN/1))

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is really tricky, the closest I've come is to swap . for [^>] as unless you specify in the regex parameters . will not match new line characters.

```
<img((?!alt\=\".*\")[^>])*((?!title\=\".*\")[^>])*>
```

But parsing html with regex is not really recommended and you can see by [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1rLvr/2). Even with a limited number of test cases its going to be very hard to catch everything. Parameters can be in any order, they can contain escaped characters and tags can be butted up against each other.

I suppose you know how clean your HTML is how valid and what the values are in the properties. Maybe most of the test cases I've highlighted do not apply to you? but your question does not specify this. IF there are incorrect assumptions I've made please amend your question.